# MongooseError: Operation `products.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am using Youtube tutorial about API using MongoDB and mongoose. However,I am keep getting this error whenever I do POST something on Postman.
"MongooseError: Operation `products.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://dusdn1102:" + process.env.MONGO_PW + "@node-rest-shop.wvxmj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  client.close();
});
```

I am using visual studio code 1.57.1 and the version of MongoDB is 4.4.10.
Please can someone help me??

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
.then(()=>console.log("DB Connected"))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

if you're using the mongoose model use this connection setting or as mentioned in [mongoose website](https://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the help!  It didn't work and it gave me another error which says, 
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I was missing the mongodb:// at the beggining of the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mongoose to create a connection with the MongoDB. Add the following code to your app.js or server.js first.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uri = "mongodb+srv://dusdn1102:" + process.env.MONGO_PW + "@node-rest-shop.wvxmj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error: "));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected successfully");
});
```

Use this to open a connection and then proceed with the insert operation.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately it didn't work... and by "add the following code", do you mean replace it or write them as a new code? Sorry I'm totally new to this and still learning them!

Comment: You need to replace your code with this one. Your code is creating a connection to mongoDB, but mongoose will not know about it. But, the code I shared will let mongoose create connection with mongoDB for you.